# Radio Button Text Wrap

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8.1, word-wrap

For some reason I cannot get this code to work in my program.
It just cuts off mid-word when it overflows the width.
I think I am doing everything right.
Can anyone help me?

```
<RadioButton x:Name="answer_4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="96" Margin="809,374,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="482" FontSize="22" Foreground="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ContentControl>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </ContentControl>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: remove content control and check

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="answer_4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="96" Margin="809,374,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="482" FontSize="22" Foreground="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <RadioButton.Content>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Your_Long_Text_Here" />
    </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: that didn't work either. Can't use the Text="" because the text is being fed dynamically.

Comment: Can you please tell me how the text is being fed?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
<RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </DataTemplate>
</RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
```